# How to control quoting of original message when replying?

Tags: email, message-mode, notmuch

I'm trying to set up [`notmuch`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NotMuch) for sending and receiving my Gmail email, and I think `notmuch` uses `message-mode` for its reply function. I tried setting `message-citation-line-function` to `nil`, but replying still quotes the entire message with a `>` prefix on each line. But that didn't work. How do I set it so that when I reply to a message, the sender's original message doesn't get quoted at all, in standard Gmail style?

Comment: I don't use that utility, but a quick grep of the Emacs source code turned up some likely suspects -- the `message-cite-function` is frequently set to `'message-cite-original`; and there are a few alist for a variety of settings -- e.g., `message-cite-gmail-style`.  Also of interest is `message-cite-style`.  Sorry that I can't be more of assistance, but perhaps those variables will give you a lead in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing all these variables to `message-cite-style-gmail` or to nil, but I was not able to get message-mode to remove the leading `>` at the beginning of each line.

Comment: For what it's worth, Gmail *does* quote the original message, it just does so by indenting with four spaces instead of using `>`.

Comment: None of this works. When I hit `r` on a message in notmuch there is no amount of `message-*` variables I can have set that will change the way it formats the message citations.

Answer (score 3):

The intended way to achieve Gmail-style citations is the following:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'message
  (setq message-cite-style message-cite-style-gmail))
```

Inspecting the value and documentation of the alist `message-cite-style-gmail` provides further insight into the involved settings:

```el
(defconst message-cite-style-gmail
  '((message-cite-function          'message-cite-original)
    (message-citation-line-function 'message-insert-formatted-citation-line)
    (message-cite-reply-position    'above)
    (message-yank-prefix            "    ")
    (message-yank-cited-prefix      "    ")
    (message-yank-empty-prefix      "    ")
    (message-citation-line-format   "On %e %B %Y %R, %f wrote:\n"))
  "Message citation style used by Gmail. Use with `message-cite-style'.")
```

The `message-yank-*-prefix` variables are the most relevant to your question; see their documentation for more information.

Note also that `message-cite-style-gmail` is only provided for convenience; you can of course customise any one of the variables involved individually or by setting `message-cite-style` to a custom alist.

For completeness, see also the documentation of `message-cite-style`:

> `message-cite-style` is a variable defined in `message.el`.
>
> Documentation:
>
> The overall style to be used when yanking cited text.
>   Value is either `nil` (no variable overrides) or a let-style list
>   of pairs `(VARIABLE VALUE)` that will be bound in
>   `message-yank-original` to do the quoting.
>
> Presets to impersonate popular mail agents are found in the
>   `message-cite-style-*` variables.  This variable is intended for
>   use in `gnus-posting-styles`, such as:
>
> `((posting-from-work-p) (eval (setq-local message-cite-style message-cite-style-outlook)))`
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 24.1 of Emacs.