# How can I get emacs notmuch to format replies the same way gmail does

Tags: notmuch, message-mode

I have seen this question!
[How to control quoting of original message when replying?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14625/how-to-control-quoting-of-original-message-when-replying)

None of that actually works. When I am in `notmuch` and I hit `r` on a message there is no amount of `message-cite-*` variables I can have customized that will do anything about the way that reply to sender email is formatted.

Does anyone have this working? I want to reply from emacs and have messages look exactly as if I had sent them using the gmail app to the people receiving my emails. I want threaded conversations to work, I want folding of cited text to work. How can I make this happen? Am I even on the right track with these `message-cite-*` vars?

Answer (score 1):

I GOT IT!!!

```
(with-eval-after-load 'message
  (setq message-cite-style message-cite-style-gmail)
  (setq message-citation-line-function 'message-insert-formatted-citation-line))
```

The `message-citation-line-function` was the absolute key to this.

EDIT: Still seeing that sometimes gmail replies are fine, and other times they aren't. It's very inconsistent. In order to use emacs as a mail client, recipients must not be distracted by strange formatting differences of my emails. I have been unable to achieve that.